# Video player that allows seeking to a specific point

Tags: video, avi, playback

I need a video player that will allow me to seek to a specific point in a video. Using a slider is not accurate enough. Which video players have this feature?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[**Media Player Classic Home Cinema**](http://mpc-hc.sourceforge.net/) allows you to jump to a *very* specific time.

Just hit <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd> to bring up the `Go To...` dialog box.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Almost all have the feature , try [VLC](http://www.videolan.org).
Go to Playback > Jump to Specific Time

Comment: It only allows seconds to be specified. That's not accurate enough.

Comment: are you seeking to go to a specific frame in the video ?

Answer (score 1):

I know mplayer has an option "`-sb <byte position>`", which I guess would be pretty accurate. To my knowledge it doesn't  allow you to seek by millisecond though, which I guess is what you're looking for.